# Solutions for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The motion of a particle moving along the x-axis obeys the differential equation:

$ \ddot x - 4 \dot x + 4x =-t^2 $

Find the solution for $ x(t)$, given $ x(0)=0 $ and $ \dot x (0) = 0 $.

---

Can this be solved by treating it as a second-order non-homogenous differential equation? If so, re-formatting the questions equation, would it be:

$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} - 4 \frac{dx}{dt}+4x=-t^2$  ?

Comment: A second order non-homogeneous differential equation is exactly what it is. And yes, what you have written is the same problem (assuming the initial values you give).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using constant coefficient method we solve for two solutions $x_h$ and $x_p$ where the general solution is $x_g=x_h+x_p$

Solving for $x_h$ implies that we solve the homogeneous system $x'' -4x'+ 4x=0$ which has the characteristic equation

$$\lambda^2 -4\lambda +4 = 0 \implies ( \lambda-2)^2=0 \implies \lambda_{1,2}=2 $$

So, $$x_h(t)=c_1e^{2t}+c_2te^{2t}$$

Solving for $x_p$ we use the method of undetermined coefficients and we let $$x_p(t)= \alpha t^2+\beta t +\omega $$ and we solve the original DE.

We have:
$$x_p'=2\alpha t+\beta$$  $$x''_p=2\alpha$$

PLugging that into the non homogeneous DE:

$$ 2\alpha - 4( 2\alpha t+\beta ) + 4(\alpha t^2+\beta t +\omega) = -t^2$$

$$ (4\alpha)t^2 + (-8\alpha+4\beta) t + (2\alpha - 4\beta+4\omega) = -t^2$$

$$ \implies 4\alpha = -1 \implies \alpha= \frac{-1}{4}$$$$ \implies-8\alpha+4\beta=0 \implies \beta = \frac{-1}{2} $$$$ \implies 2\alpha - 4\beta+4\omega=0 \implies \omega= \frac{-3}{8}$$

So in we have $$ x_p(t)= \frac{-1}{4}t^2 - \frac{1}{2}t -\frac{3}{8} $$

So the general solution is:

$$x_g(t)= x_h + x_p = c_1e^{2t}+c_2te^{2t} + \frac{-1}{4}t^2 - \frac{1}{2}t -\frac{3}{8} $$

Finally, given the initial conditions $x(0)=0$  and  $x'(0)= 0 $, we find that the constants are $c_1=3$ and$ c_2=-2$ to get the unique solution:

$$ x(t)=  3e^{2t}-2te^{2t} + \frac{-1}{4}t^2 - \frac{1}{2}t -\frac{3}{8} $$

Comment: To find the $ c_1$ and $c_2$ constants, do you substitute the initial condition into $x_g (t)$ as $x(0)=0$, and then take the first derivative of $x_g (t)$ with respect to t, then substituting in $x'(0)=0$? Then solve the two equations for $c_1$ and $c_2$ ? @CivilSigma

Comment: should $x_h (t) = c_1 e^{2t} +c_2 t e^{2t}$ instead of $x_h (t) = c_1 e^{2x} + c_2 x e^{2x} $?

Comment: For your first comment, that is true and that gives us  two equations with two unknowns which will give you a unique solution. As for your second comment, I should replace the x's with t's (sorry about that)!

Answer (score 2):

As usual you must solve the homogenous equation and then find the particular solution to the non-homogeneous equation.

For the homogeneous part you use the ansatz $x=e^{rt}$

For the non-homogenous part, you can make a different ansatz, such as $x=At^2+Bt+C$.

Hopefully this is familiar.

Comment: Did you mix up non-homogeneous and homogeneous ?